# Railway.js + Jade crashes when a route to '/client' is defined

Tags: node.js, pug, railway.js

I get this weird error when I add a route '/client' in Railway.js:

```
500 ReferenceError: jade is not defined
```

I get this for any valid route in my app, not only '/client'. This line seems to be added to the top of my Jade compiled templates, and is what causes the exception:

```
var attrs = jade.attrs, escape = jade.escape, rethrow = jade.rethrow;
```

It is not present in the compiled templates unless I define a route do '/client'.

'/client/:id?', '/clients', everything else works, only '/client'.

Anyone has a clue?

Comment: Which version of jade/express/railway are you using? What if switch to express ~2.x?

Comment: @Anatoliy even today i have this bug - express 3.1

Comment: @vittore are you able to reproduce in compound? if so, don't hesistate to open issue (https://github.com/1602/compound/issues/new) with all information we need to reproduce issue from scratch.

Comment: @Anatoliy I belive it is Jade bug, as I'm not using compound.js , I'm using express.js with jade

Comment: @Anatoliy and I even found this open issue https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/914

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact same error when I was working on an ExpressJS app using jade templates. I figured out it was only happening on pages where I passed a local variable named `client`. E.g.

```
res.render('admin/project_new', {
  title: 'Edit Project',
  message: req.flash(),
  client: someClient
});
```

I think `client` is a reserved word when rendering jade files (or maybe something else, I'm still kinda new to Node.js). I was able to fix it by changing it to this:

```
res.render('admin/project_new', {
  title: 'Edit Project',
  message: req.flash(),
  theClient: someClient
});
```

Comment: Hah! I'm having the exact same issue now. But why is `client` special?